# I'd like to know what "get around to" implies

Tags: meaning

Here's the sentence I get mixed up.

> Until a year ago, I **never got around to** meeting the people.

I'd like to know if this means "I couldn't meet the people because I don't have enough time or something" or "I didn't want to meet the people"

I'd like to know what "get around to" implies

Answer (score 3):

It means "I didn't make it happen", with an implication that I intended to, or wanted to, but there was some obstacle. It is not specific about what kind of obstacle that was - whether it was my busyness, my mental state, obstructions from outside, or something else.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to your question is "yes". (In other words, **both** of the meanings you supply are valid ways to interpret the sentence.)

A little more context would clarify. Consider:

> Until a year ago, I never got around to meeting the people. I was too busy.
>
> Until a year ago, I never got around to meeting the people. I was too shy.

Now the reasons are a little more clear.

Note: Unless you were referring to some specific group of people, there's a good chance I would leave out the word *the* before *people*:

> Until a year ago, I never got around to meeting people.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I got it. then Can I use like the followings?  "Until a year ago, I was so shy I didn't get around to meeting people" or "Until a year ago, I was too busy I couldn't get around to meeting people"

Comment: I'd word those like this: _Until a year ago, I was **too** shy **to** get around to meeting people_. Or perhaps even more simply" _Until a year ago, I was too shy to meet people._ You really don't need the "get around to" when it's worded like that – it's clunky.